# best python module to update huge excel which has pivot table (with openpyxl, win32com and Pyexcelerate facing different issues)

Tags: python, excel

The modules i have tried:

- `openpyxl` -  I am able to update the sheet, but the problem is it is removing exisitng pivot table in the sheet
- `win32com` - getting:

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

when using the below code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Interactive = True
#xl.Visible = True
wb=xl.Workbooks.Item("Inforce_Fire_Validation.xlsx")
ws=wb.Sheets("BV Cube")
print(ws.Range('A5'))
ws.Range('A5').Value=55
```

- Pyexcelerate - Unable to find update excel documentation

Answer (score 0):

I usually use pandas [read excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to load the excel sheet as a  pandas data frame. I then use python to edited the data frame.
And then use the pandas [to_excel() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to  write a new excel file. Maybe this helps

Comment: Then how to keep pivot table and DB  connections  when we read as df